# Openssl error in mongosh in amazon linux ami

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2, mongodb-query, openssl, mongo-shell

I'm encountering an OpenSSL configuration error when attempting to use mongosh. The error message I receive is as follows:

```
mongosh: OpenSSL configuration error:
00B927B69E7F0000:error:030000A9:digital envelope routines:alg_module_init:unknown option:../deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/evp/evp_cnf.c:61:name=rh-allow-sha1-signatures, value=yes
```

I'm using MongoDB on **ami linux 2023**  with OpenSSL version **3.0.8**. I've tried setting the OPENSSL_VERSION environment variable to match my OpenSSL version, but the error persists.